# Conditionally use library

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to add [flutter_sound_lite](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound_lite) to my application, Currently my Android API level is 16 and iOS target is 9.0
Flutter Sound requires an iOS 10.0 SDK and Android API level 21

I want to keep my API level (16) and iOS target(9.0), and add Flutter Sound too, just don't use it on old devices, How can I do it?

For android I add the following line in manifest

```xml
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.dooboolab.fluttersound, com.dooboolab.TauEngine" />
```

But in android log cat I have error

```
04-17 10:27:08.182 2973-2973/ir.karget E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.AudioAttributes$Builder', referenced from method androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Builder.setSound
```

Comment: You can add `android:minSdkVersion="21" ` in the sdk tag

Comment: @ProblematicDude I want to support minSdkVersion  16